# how to copy files based on filename lenght using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-processing

I need to batch copy a sort of file extensions from subfolders to specific folders for each location.

All folders have a 6 digit number
let's say folder Rood folder: `BATCH`

```
Subfolder 1: 000000
Subfolder 2: 111111
```

despite their extensions, most files have the name as the subfolder but some of them may have extra alphanumeric characters, therefore the script should grab only the ones that are not larger than 6 digits.

Example Subfolder1: `000000.pdf` `000000.eps` the script would need to grab all pdf within subfolders and export them to a PDF exclusive new folder, and the same would apply for eps files.

I know nothing about powershell but I know that something like this would work for an specific subfolder but I'm still missing the parts where it distributes them to a new PDFONLY  and EPSONLY folders and the fact the I want to apply this to all the folders whiting the root folder.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\BATCH\*" -Include *.pdf,*.eps -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination D:\
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group all the files by their extension and then loop over each group of objects, create a new folder with the desired name and lastly copy all objects of each group to their folders.

```
$target = 'D:\' # Set destination here

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\BATCH\* -Include *.py, *.ps1 -Recurse |
    Group-Object Extension | ForEach-Object {
        # Example of `$folderName` would be `PDF ONLY`
        $folderName = '{0} ONLY' -f $_.Name.TrimStart('.').ToUpper()
        $destination = Join-Path $target -ChildPath $folderName
        # If the `$destination` folder doesn't exist
        if(-not (Test-Path $destination)) {
            # Create it
            $null = New-Item $destination -ItemType Directory
        }
        Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_.Group.FullName -Destination $destination
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I appreaciate it. I'm sorry I'm just not able to follow where the files group will be copied, I would like them move to a "Classified groups" folder

Comment: @NotraceNotracking thats what the code is doing. You can test it with a set of files

Comment: Sorry, my bad... now I see that the destination it set at the begining of the code, will give a try and let you know. thanks for your help

Comment: hi @Santiago Squarzon, it worked. But I'm affraid  I did not explain my need clearly. I said all files match the folder name but that's incorrect I will fix my question. Some folders may have more than 2 pdf files eg. 000000.pdf and 000000BB.pdf thats why I asked in the the subject that it should stick to the filename lenght. I need to grab only the ones that don't exceed more than 6 digits on their name. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Santiago's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71656634/9898643) but with an extra filter and without grouping you can do this:

```
$destination = 'X:\somewhere'

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\BATCH" -Include '*.pdf','*.eps' -File -Recurse |
Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '^\d{6}$' } |   # filter files with a BaseName of just 6 digits
ForEach-Object {
    $targetPath = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath ('{0}ONLY' -f $_.Extension.TrimStart(".").ToUpper())
    # make sure the target path exists
    # for directories, using the -Force switch either creates a new folder 
    # or returns the DirectoryInfo object of an existing folder.
    $null = New-Item -Path $targetPath -ItemType Directory -Force
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetPath
}
```

Comment: Hi @Theo I'm pretty sure I set the destination and Path correctly but nothing is happening.

Comment: @NotraceNotracking Can you show me the paths you're using and does the source path contain any .pdf or .eps files with a name consisting of just 6 digits and an extension? I just added switch `-File` to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet to make sure you only process files, not directories too.